# Применение select в Angular в модальном окне

Tags: html, angularjs, select

Есть модальное окно:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="createDocTemplate.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalInstance.title}}</h4>
    </div>
    <form name="createDocForm">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':createDocForm.docNumber.$invalid}">
                <label for="docNumber" class="control-label">№ документа*</label>
                <input type="text" required
                       ng-model="modalInstance.form.docNumber" class="form-control" id="docNumber" name="docNumber">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':createDocForm.docDate.$invalid}">
                <label for="docDate" class="control-label">Дата*</label>
                <input type="text" required
                       ng-model="modalInstance.form.docDate" class="form-control" id="docDate" name="docDate">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':createDocForm.correspondent.$invalid}">
                <label for="correspondent" class="control-label">Корреспондент (ФИО)*</label>

                <select ng-model="modalInstance.form.correspondent" class="form-control" id="correspondent" name="correspondent">
                        <option ng-repeat="user in demoApp.users">{{user.secondName}} {{user.firstName}} {{user.middleName}}</option>
                        <option>lol</option>

                </select>

            <div ng-show="modalInstance.formError" class="form-group">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Ошибка:</span>
                    Заполните обязательные поля
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</script>
```

Проблема в том, что в нем не работает данный select. В котором должен выбираться корреспондент.

Однако за пределами модального окна данный select отлично работает.

В чем проблема?

Comment: Начните с того, что приведите код вызова данного модального окна

Comment: Все получилось решить, просто в модальном окне не был объявлен demoApp.users